# Error calling generic method

Tags: java, class, generics, methods

I have two generic classes

```
class Value<T>{...}

class Parameter<T>{...}
```

And i want to call a method from another class (Params)

```
    public <T> void put(Parameter<T> key, Value<T> value) {
    parameters.put(key, value);
}
```

And from my main class i want to call it with two objects Value and Parameter but with the Type  in this way:

```
 Value<Integer> v1 = new Value<Integer>(2);
 Parameter<Integer> p1 = new Parameter<Integer>(3);
 Params params = new Params();
 params.put(p1,v1);
```

And i receive this error from Eclipse:

```
The method put(Parameter<T>, Value<T>) in the type Parameters is not applicable for the arguments (Parameter<Integer>, Value<Integer>)
```

Any hint of how can i call this method without having this error? This classes were not developed by me, so I'm trying to call them without success.

Comment: Are there any constraints placed on `T`?

Comment: What do you mean with a constraint placed on T @JeroenVannevel? The only strange i see at the beggining of the class Params is this: @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes").

Comment: The generic declaration is ok. Are you sure that you don't have more than one class named `Parameter` or `Value` and that you use classes from one package, while the method in the `Params` class expect instances from a different package?

Comment: @jambjo you were right, i have realized i was using the class Value from the same package and from one library in one jar, so deleting the class in my package now there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot derive what your  class is, so you have to give it a hint:

```
params.<Integer>put(p1,v1);
```

Wouldn't it make sense to make the Params class generic?